# How to change a loaded video source from other html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Basically I've an html file which contains all the elements needed for my web app videos.
So Now I'm in a position where I need to counts numbers of user videos and show them to user.

Script:

```
for(var i=1;i<(s.length)-2;i++){
    $('#vid_c_'+i).append('<div id="vid_'+i+'"></div>');
    $("<div>").load("video_content.html",function(index) {
        return function() {
            $(this).find('.video').attr({id: 'video_id_'+index});
            $("#vid_"+index).append($(this).html());
        }
     })(i));

     var myElem = document.getElementById('video_id_'+i);
     if (myElem === null) alert('does not exist!');
     $(this).find('#video_id_'+i).attr('src', video_src[i-1]);
     console.log(video_src[i-1]+ "    "+"#video_id_"+i);
}
```

So Basically What happen is that for loop creates `(s.length)-2` which is the amount of user videos and load video elements in a div and for each video it specifies a unique ID increased by value of `i`. So far it works fine now I need to specify video source which is assigned in `video_src[i-1]`.

As you can see I've `myElem` which test if the element exists or not And the result is the it alerts saying `does not exist` even though I have loaded my  video element And I can see it in my browser inspect mode with the Id assigned fine which makes the next line for assigning video source not to work.  I also have tried:

```
$(this).find('.video').attr({id: 'video_id_'+index, 'src': video_src[i-1]});
```

and inside `.load()` function `video_src` shows to be undefined.

In my `console.log` it show the exact video source as needs to be assigned.

So I would really appreciate if someone tell me how to assign video source each time the video element is loaded from my `video_content.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, Based on all my research And tests I had I came up that inside `.load(function(){});` I can't access data of current page because it's executing script from my `video_cntent.html` file. So In order to set the source of my video element I created two for Loops:

```
for(var i=1;i<(s.length)-2;i++){
    var video_src = video_source[i-1];
    localStorage.setItem('Item_'+i, video_src);
    $('#vid_c_'+i).append('<div class="move_2" id="vidi_'+i+'"></div>');
}
                 
for(var i=1;i<(s.length)-2;i++){
    $("<div>").load("video_cntent.html",(function(index) {
     return function() {
        var retrieveitem  = localStorage.getItem('Item_'+index);
        $(this).find('#vidi_'+index).attr({id: 'video_id_'+index, 'src': retrieveitem});
        }
     })(i));
}
```

As you can see in my first loop I am accessing `video_source` and storing it in `localStorage` and it stores all my video sources based on value of `i`.

And in my second Loop I'm retrieving all the stored data again based on value of `i` and using it to set source of my video element.